# CSS images and Retina displays

Tags: html, css

Using Chrome on a Macbook Pro Retina and Chrome on Windows , I'm getting some strange behaviour whilst trying to display images for non-retina and retina displays.

I have a number of square images and the CSS is as follows:

```
/* NON RETINA */

/* style for all square images so no need to repeat */
.sq-img-small {
  background-size: 239px 239px;
  width:239px;
  height:239px;
  float:left;
  margin:0 0 20px 10px;
}

.sq-img-small.img-small-1 {
  background: url('../images/squares/food1.jpg') no-repeat top left;
}


/* RETINA */
@media 
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),(-moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dppx) { 

  .sq-img-small.img-small-1 {
    background: url('../images/squares/food1.2x.jpg') no-repeat top left;
  }
```

My HTML is:

```
<div class="sq-img-small img-small-1"></div>
```

The non-retina displays the images perfectly well but the retina images are not displaying as they should. I cannot see the whole image in the `div` - it appears to have zoomed in on the image so I can only see a fraction.

If I add:

```
background-size: 239px 239px;
width:239px;
height:239px;
```

into the retina `.sq-img-small.img-small-1` block then it displays fine but I didn't think I would need to do this as it should inherit from earlier right? Or is inheritance affected by the `@media` block in some way?

=============== UPDATE ==============

After further investigation, it seems that setting the style for all square images and then specifying the path to each image works fine when not inside `@media` block but doesn't work when I do the same inside one.

Answer (score 2):

Just giving you an example. Try this solution.

```
/* for low resolution display */

.image {

    background-image: url(/path/to/my/lowreslogo.png);
    background-size: 200px 300px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;

}

/* for high resolution display */

@media only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
.image {    
    background: url(/path/to/my/highreslogo.png) no-repeat;    
    background-size: 200px 400px;    
/* rest of your styles... */

}
}
```

Comment: In my question I mentioned that I can get it to work in the way you suggested but I'm trying to avoid unnecessary code. Surely if I've already set the background size then I shouldn't need to do it again.

Comment: also bear in mind that I have multiple images to show in divs. Your example is really only suitable for one image

Comment: while the example might not be plug and play to match your css styles, his approach matches other examples on various html websites, including [this one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-right-way-to-retinafy-your-websites--net-31793). Just change the `.image` to `.img-small-1`. The important differences are how the @media query is structured.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible reasons for your attempt not working. The `background-size` property is not inherited, and when the property is not specified through a `background`-shorthand property, such a property resets the `background-size`.

Thus, you cannot expect the `background-size`to be inherited from `.sq-img-small` to `.sq-img-small.img-small-1` (but this may not be a problem, as they reference the same element), and because you use the shorthand property on `.sq-img-small.img-small-1` you reset the `background-size`.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size.

As for the working non-retina image; is your non-retina image perhaps the coorect size (239px by 239px) to begin with?

As your current `background-size`-rule is not effective you could move it into the shorthand property, and end up with 1 less line of css, but a bit more redundancy in the `background`-rules. This seems like a small sacrifice however, as you already have `no-repeat top left`in there:

```
/* style for all square images so no need to repeat */
.sq-img-small {
  width:239px;
  height:239px;
  float:left;
  margin:0 0 20px 10px;
}

.sq-img-small.img-small-1 {
  background: url('../images/squares/food1.jpg') no-repeat top left / 239px 239px;
}


/* RETINA */
@media 
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),(-moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dppx) { 

  .sq-img-small.img-small-1 {
    background: url('../images/squares/food1.2x.jpg') no-repeat top left / 239px 239px;
  }
```

Alternatively, you could try moving the shorthand out into the general case, but it seems you tried this in your update, and it didn't work:

```
/* style for all square images so no need to repeat */
.sq-img-small {
  background: no-repeat top left / 239px 239px;
  width:239px;
  height:239px;
  float:left;
  margin:0 0 20px 10px;
}

.sq-img-small.img-small-1 {
  background-image: url('../images/squares/food1.jpg');
}


/* RETINA */
@media 
  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),(-moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dppx) { 

  .sq-img-small.img-small-1 {
    background-image: url('../images/squares/food1.2x.jpg');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing the dpi and dppx numbers:

according to this website, http://brettjankord.com/2012/11/28/cross-browser-retinahigh-resolution-media-queries/,

> The dppx unit is a new unit that is equal to the device-pixel-ratio value webkit uses.
>
> However, the dppx unit is not as widely supported as the dpi unit. The dppx unit is supported in FF 16.0+ and Opera 12.10+.
>
> IE does not currently support dppx units.

(the site is a little old, and dppx is supported by Chrome since v29)

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and ( min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and ( min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

whats the difference between dppx and dpi?

**DPI**

> This unit represents the number of dots per inch. A screen typically contains 72 or 96 dpi; a printed document usually reach much greater dpi.

**DPPX**

> This unit represents the number of dots per px unit. Due to the 1:96 fixed ratio of CSS in to CSS px, 1dppx is equivalent to 96dpi, that corresponds to the default resolution of images displayed in CSS as defined by image-resolution.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolution)

**device example:**

The iPhone 4 has a 3.5″ screen, at 640×960px. This calculates to a 326dpi screen, which uses 2dppi, or 2 dots per pixel. This 2dppi ratio is what 'retina' is, and why the assets are 2x the size. Furthermore, it is why the 640px width only shows as 320px to the browser, because it draws two 'dots'/pixels for every 1 CSS-based pixel. (a 1px border will be drawn on two rows of pixels)

Comment: I'm using Chrome which does support dppx - I'll update my question

Comment: See the website for more examples on good cross-browser dpi css stuff

Comment: It's not a cross-browser issue. I'm just testing it in Chrome and trying to get it to work!

Comment: But observe 192**dppx** vs 2**dppx**, the 192 is a dpi value, where the dppx is usually 1-3 tops

Comment: made the changes but no effect - will note for the future though